# Nested setTimeout alternative?

Tags: javascript

I need to execute 3 functions in a 1 sec delay.

for simplicity those functions  are :

```
console.log('1');
console.log('2');
console.log('3');
```

I could do this: ( very ugly)

```
 console.log('1')
 setTimeout(function () {
     setTimeout(function () {
         console.log('2')
         setTimeout(function () {
             console.log('3')

         }, 1000)
     }, 1000)

 }, 1000)
```

Or I could create an `array` of functions and use `setInterval` with `global` counter.

Is there any  *elegant* way of doing this ?

(p.s. function no.2 is not dependent on function number 1... hence - every sec execute  the next function.).

Comment: If they are not dependent and such, why do they need to execute at different time? (Just make sure it is required) You could simple use 3 timeouts seperatly, one at 1sec, the second at 2sec and so on...

Comment: use setTimeout with loop... for (...) { setTimeout(function() {}, 1000 * index); } or something like this

Comment: @Salketer network pressure maybe? why is that matters ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I just offered that you think 2 more minutes about it and make sure it is needed... As for network pressure, I once had a script that did multiple ajax calls one after another to finally get a full page, and most of the IE7 and IE8 users would not receive the full page. We never found what the problem was... And if let's say you have a huge application, or running on zend or something similar, loading everything in PHP memory 3 times instead of one might cause performence problem... Just wanted you to save some time if you didn't absolutely need this kind of call, sorry.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use something like this with `setTimeout`:

```
var funcs = [func1, func2, func3],
    i = 0;

function callFuncs() {
    funcs[i++]();
    if (i < funcs.length) setTimeout(callFuncs, 1000);
}
setTimeout(callFuncs, 1000); //delay start 1 sec.
```

or start by just calling callFuncs() directly.

**Update**

An `setInterval` approach (be aware of the risk of call stacking):

```
var funcs = [func1, func2, func3],
    i = 0,
    timer = setInterval(callFuncs, 1000);

function callFuncs() {
    funcs[i++]();
    if (i === funcs.length) clearInterval(timer);
}
```

Comment: this is what i thought about ( already mentioned that in my question)  - but I wanted to know if there is more solutions....

Comment: and what happens if calling callFuncs twice ?? :-) - there's only one closure - More generally this code is not re-usable.

Comment: this not clean and i might get used somewhere else. And what  if you call callFuncs 500 ms later ? ... And what if you want to chain some other functions later ? you reset i, change funcs value then call callFuncs ? ugly...

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you run it on a modern browser or have added support for array.map this is quite concise:

```
[func1, func2, func3].map(function (fun, index) {
    setTimeout(fun, 1000 + index * 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
setTimeout(function(){console.log('1')}, 1000);
setTimeout(function(){console.log('2')}, 2000);
setTimeout(function(){console.log('3')}, 3000);
```

Comment: With arrow function
`setTimeout(() => console.log('1'), 1000);
setTimeout(() => console.log('2'), 2000);
setTimeout(() => console.log('3'), 3000);`

Comment: This is elegant with one change - use an accumulator variable so that when you're tweaking one delay, you don't have to change all subsequent numbers.

Comment: You are right, that's how we'd do it in a real world code, but I prefered keeping it simple and explicit for OP.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new type of function declaration called generators in es6 (a.k.a ecmascript 6, es2015). It is incredibly useful for this situation, and makes your async code look synchronous. es6 is the latest standard of JavaScript as of 2015. It works on modern browsers but you can use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) and its javascript polyfill to use generators now even on older browsers.

[Here](http://modernweb.com/2014/02/10/replacing-callbacks-with-es6-generators/) is a tutorial on generators.

The function myDelayedMessages below is an example of a generator. Run is a helper function that takes a generator function which it calls and provides a function to advance the generator as the first argument of the generator function that it called.

```js
function delay(time, callback) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        callback();
      }, time);
}

function run(generatorFunction) {
  var generatorItr = generatorFunction(resume);
  function resume(callbackValue) {
    generatorItr.next(callbackValue);
  }
  generatorItr.next()
}

run(function* myDelayedMessages(resume) {
  for(var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
    yield delay(1000, resume);
    console.log(i);
  }
});
```

This is an overview of the code which is similar to the above tutorial's final overview.

1. `run` takes our generator and creates a resume function. run creates a
   generator-iterator object (the thing you call next on), providing
   resume.
2. Then it advances the generator-iterator one step to kick
   everything off.
3. Our generator encounters the first yield statement
   and calls delay.
4. Then the generator pauses.
5. delay completes 1000ms later and calls resume.
6. resume tells our generator to advance a single step.
7. Our generator continues from the spot it yielded at then console.logs i, which is 1, then continues the loop
8. Our generator encounters the second call to yield,
   calls delay and pauses again.
9. delay waits 1000ms and ultimately
   calls the resume callback. resume advances the generator again.
10. Our generator continues from the spot it yielded at then console.logs i, which is 2, then continues the loop.
11. delay waits 1000ms and ultimately
    calls the resume callback. resume advances the generator again.
12. Our generator continues from the spot it yielded at then console.logs i, which is 3, then continues and the loop finishes.
13. There are no more calls to yield, the generator finishes executing.

Answer (score 2):

with async/await

```js
const pause = _ => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, _));

async function main() {
  await pause(1000);
  console.log('one');
  
  await pause(1000);
  console.log('two');
  
  await pause(1000);
  console.log('three');
}

main();
```

note this works in a loop too

```js
const pause = _ => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, _));

async function main() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    await pause(1000);
    console.log(i + 1);
  }
}

main();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think most simple way to do this is to create some closures within a function.
First i'll recall that you have big interest in using `setInterval`, since the overhead of the `setTimeout` might have it trigger 10ms off target. So especially if using short (<50ms) interval, prefer setInterval.
So we need to store the function array, the index of latest executed function, and an interval reference to stop the calls.

```
function chainLaunch(funcArray, time_ms) {
  if (!funcArray || !funcArray.length) return;
  var fi = 0; // function index
  var callFunction = function () {
      funcArray[fi++]();
      if (fi==funcArray.length)
              clearInterval(chainInterval);
   } ;
  var chainInterval = setInterval( callFunction, time_ms);
}
```

Rq  : You might want to copy the function array ( `funcArray = funcArray.slice(0);` )
Rq2 : You might want to loop within the array
Rq3 : you might want to accept additionnal arguments to chainlaunch. retrieve them with `var funcArgs = arguments.slice(3);`  and use apply on the functions : `funcArray[fi++].apply(this,funcArgs);`

Anyway the following test works :

```
var f1 = function() { console.log('1'); };
var f2 = function() { console.log('2'); };
var f3 = function() { console.log('3'); };

var fArr = [f1, f2, f3];

chainLaunch(fArr, 1000);
```

as you can see in this fiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/F9UJv/1/
(open the console)

Answer (score 0):

There are here two methods. One with setTimeout and anotherone with setInterval. The first one is better in my opinion.

```js
for(var i = 1; i++; i<=3) {
  setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(i);
    }, 1000*i);
}
// second choice:
var i = 0;
var nt = setInterval(function() {
      if(i == 0) return i++;
      console.log(i++);
      if(i>=3) clearInterval(nt);
    }, 1000);
```