# nested setTimeout functions when subfunctions include varying delays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of about 100 arguments that all take different amounts of time to run through a given function. Each is a brief animation on a page, animating a different part depending on the argument, and they take about 1-3 seconds each.

I checked this: [Nested setTimeout alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574571/nested-settimeout-alternative)

...but it only works when the subfunctions take the same amount of time,

I can collect the arguments in an array in the order they should go, i.e.:

args= [arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4...]

Currently my calls looks like this:

```
 setTimeout(myfunction(arg1), 3000);
 setTimeout(myfunction(arg2), 5000);
 setTimeout(myfunction(arg3), 7500);
 setTimeout(myfunction(arg4), 8500);...
```

I'd really like to be able to have code that says "when myfunction(arg1) is finished, wait 500 milliseconds and then execute myfunction(arg2), then when that is finished wait 500 ms and execute func3, etc."

I don't know how to incorporate that into either the running of the setTimeouts or the definition of myfunction().

Thank you.

Comment: Does `myFunction` returns another function? Else it doesn't really make sense to have a timeout there as they all will be executed at the same time. here you are executing the `myFunction` right away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Promises` are a perfect way to chain async operations. 
If you could consider changing the body of `myFunction` so that it returns a `promise` then you could chain those operation easily.

The body of `myFunction` would look like this

```
function myFunction(args, time) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      // here you do your stuff
      resolve(); // resolve the promise when it's done
    }, time);
  })
}
```

And you call it this way

```
var args = [
  { args: "", timeout: 100 },
  { args: "", timeout: 300 }
]

var promise = Promise.resolve();

args.forEach(function (animation) {
  promise = promise
    .then(myFunction.bind(null, animation.args, animation.timeout))
    // ^ chaining promise so that they fire one after another
})
```

Comment: Hi, can you clarify what the 100 and 300 do here? If possible, I would like to avoid having to specify the duration of each argument's run. Promises sound very promising!

Comment: If you don't want to specify them for each argument, just put your desired wait time in the .then call instead of animation.timeout - or replace the integer value with a function that returns it

Comment: Oh, I though each step needs to wait different amount of time, that's why I added the `timeout` attribute, but you can definitely get rid of it if you need to wait the same amount of time at each step :)

Answer (score 2):

You can just schedule your next task in the callback of the previous `setTimeout`, like that:

```
var tasks = [
    { arg : "arg1", delay : 3000},
    { arg : "arg2", delay: 2000},
    { arg : "arg3", delay : 2500}
];

function myFunction(arg) {
    console.log(new Date(),arg);
}

function schedule() { 
    var task = tasks.shift();
    if(task) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            myFunction(task.arg);               
            if(tasks.length) schedule();
        },task.delay);
    }
}

schedule();
```

This code will call `myFunction("arg1")` in 3000ms, then `myFunction("arg2")` in +2000ms and then `myFunction("arg3")` in +2500ms.

Each time it will remove (shift) the first element of your "task list",
and then stop once it is empty.

Take a note that this code will mutate your `tasks` array (by removing the next task from it on an each iteration), so you won't be able to reuse it.

If that is a problem, just use an explicit index to address the next task:

```
function schedule(tasks,i) {
    if(i<tasks.length) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            myFunction(tasks[i].arg);               
            if(i+1<tasks.length) schedule(tasks,i+1);
        },tasks[i].delay);
    }
}

schedule(tasks,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to sort out this problem is a promise chain:

```js
var args = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
var i = 0;

function doStuff(arg) {
  //do stuff
  console.log(arg)
}

function getPromise(cb, arg, time){
  return function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
      setTimeout(function(){
        cb(arg)
        resolve()
      }, time)
    })
  }
}

var promise_chain = Promise.resolve();
while (args[i]) {
  promise_chain  = promise_chain.then(getPromise(doStuff, args[i++], 500))
}
```

This code will generate a bunch of promises. Each one waits 500ms to resolve itself and execute next bunch of code. Hope this help.