# How to continuously animate between 4 frames

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I'm trying to make a platforming game and need to animate between 4 frames. I have some code but that creates erratic animation. Here's my player object:

```
  var player = {};
  player.x = 0;
  player.y = 0;
  player.vx = 0;
  player.vy = 0;
  player.facing = "";
  player.jumping = false;
  player.shooting = false;
  player.animating = true;
  player.animationSpeed = 100;
  player.frame = 0;
  player.img = new Image();
  player.src = null;
  //I edited out the frames for length issues. They are player.frame0 through player.frame31
  player.physics = function() {
    document.onkeydown = function(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        player.vx -= player.vx;
        player.vx -= 3;
        player.facing = "left";
        player.animating = true;
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        player.vy -= player.vy;
        player.vy -= 10;
        player.jumping = true;
        player.animating = true;
      } else if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        player.vx -= player.vx;
        player.vx += 3;
        player.facing = "right";
        player.animating = true;
      } else if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        player.shooting = true;
        player.animating = true;
      }
    }
    document.onkeyup = function() {
      player.animating = false;
      player.jumping = false;
      player.vx = 0;
      player.vy = 0;
    }
    if (player.facing.toLowerCase() === "right" && player.animating === true) {
      setInterval(function() {
        player.src = player.frame0;
        setTimeout(function() {
          player.src = player.frame1;
          setTimeout(function() {
            player.src = player.frame2;
            setTimeout(function() {
              player.src = player.frame3;
            },player.animationSpeed);
          },player.animationSpeed);
        },player.animationSpeed);
      },player.animationSpeed);
    }
    drawImg(player,player.x,player.y);
  }
```

Is there a better way to do this? The player.physics() method is where my animation code is. It's unfinished because I can't animate the frames.

Comment: Why do you use iframes to do so ?

Comment: What are iframes?

Comment: I may not have understood your question then. Can you post the HTML code of your application ?

Comment: I don't have any. This is pure Javascript.

Comment: So, give more info on what is the `player` variable, because we don't know what that is.

Comment: Try googling “nested settimeout” and you’ll get several results discussing best practices  and how to do this more efficient. This question, for instance, might be of some help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574571/nested-settimeout-alternative

Answer (score 1):

Oh yes there are better ways to do it...

#### Don't *ever* change the `src` of an HTMLImage during your game play / animation.

Setting an HTMLImage's `src` is always asynchronous*. This means that by the time you ask it to be drawn, it may still be the previous image that is loaded, and you end up actually drawing the wrong image.
<sub>*Actually, in some browsers this action is made in a parallel thread and may have finished at next line of code execution, but you can't rely on that, too many parameters can interfere.</sub>

Instead, create one HTMLImage instance per file, load them all at initiation and store these HTMLImages. A convenient way to store these is in an `Array`.

```
// load images from an Array of URLs, returns an Array of HTMLImages
// accepts an callback which will fire when all images will have loaded
function loadImages(arrayOfURLs, onloadAll){
  let loaded = 0;
  function onloadSingle(e){
    if(++loaded >= arrayOfURLs.length){
      onloadAll();
    }
  }
  return arrayOfURLs.map(function(url) {
    let img = new Image();
    img.onload = onloadSingle;
    img.src = url;
    return img;
  });
}
```

#### Don't nest multiple timing functions like that

`setTimeout` and `setInterval` are not precise timing functions, they only tell the browser to wait at least the time parameter you passed to it, but you don't know how late it was, and by nesting this you are adding more and more imprecision. At the end, you may end up with your last `setTimeout` being called after the next `setInterval`. Add to this the now fixed asynchronicity of your image loading and you created a nice random machine.

Instead, create one *animation loop*, and check the current time in this unique loop to update your logic accordingly.
When dealing with image rendered animations (i.e which end is the screen), the best way to create such *animation loop* is to use the [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) (*rAF*) method.
This method accepts a callback function which will be called before next screen refresh (approximately @60fps on most computers). This allows you to only do the updates when really needed, at a constant frame rate.
The callbacks passed to it will have a single argument, an HighResTimeStamp which will allow you to base your logic on precise timing.

A very basic animation loop may look like this:

```
function animLoop(time){
  logicUpdate(time); // do your logics update based on time + external user gestures
  draw(); // separate your drawing operations
  requestAnimationFrame(animLoop); // call again at next screen refresh
}
```

Then all you need to do is to store the currentIndex of your Array of images, and increment it at every interval, modulo the length of your Array - 1

```
// at every interval that you may decide based on rAF time
currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % (images.length - 1);
currentImage = images[ currentIndex ];
```

```js
// that code could be better arranged with Classes, please don't use as is
// I only tried to make it simple to understand how everything works independently

const urls = [
  'x8hwadksz3bz7za/banana-1.png',
  'hl7d2kzr4yvoi37/banana-3.png',
  'tqrlzaujru03e9w/banana-5.png',
  'd1gbyfyiz90w152/banana-7.png'
  ].map(u=>'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/'+u);

const images = loadImages(urls, startAnimation);
images.currentIndex = 0;

function startAnimation(){
  requestAnimationFrame(function(time){
    images.lastUpdate = time; // set the initial time
    animLoop(time); // start the animation
    });
  canvas.width = images[0].width;
  canvas.height = images[1].height;
  }

function imageUpdate(time){
  // only if we passed the interval
  if(time - images.lastUpdate > image_interval.value){
    images.lastUpdate = time; // save the curent time
    // update the image to be drawn
    images.currentIndex = (images.currentIndex + 1) % (images.length - 1);
    }
  }
function logicUpdate(time){
  imageUpdate(time);
  // other logic updates
  }

function draw(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(images[images.currentIndex], 0, 0);
  }

function animLoop(time){
  logicUpdate(time); // do your logic updates based on time + external user gestures
  draw(); // separate your drawing operations
  requestAnimationFrame(animLoop); // call again at next screen refresh
}

// load images from an Array of URLs, returns an Array of HTMLImages
// accepts an callback which will fire when all images will have loaded
function loadImages(arrayOfURLs, onloadAll){
  let loaded = 0;
  function onloadSingle(e){
    if(++loaded >= arrayOfURLs.length){
      onloadAll();
    }
  }
  return arrayOfURLs.map(function(url) {
    let img = new Image();
    img.onload = onloadSingle;
    img.src = url;
    return img;
  });
}

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

```html
<label>set the image interval</label>
<input type="range" id="image_interval" min="0" max="2000" step="100" value="200"></label><br>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: I condensed your code into a single function called playerLogic. It works fine, but stops drawing the sprite if I attempt to change the image array in code. Here's the function and player object: https://pastebin.com/pBBfVgMV