# nested settimeout with irregular intervals (more sophisticated way)

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I got this recursive function with nested settimeout functions inside. The intervals should be the way the are. They are not linear(hope that is the word i need, english is not my native language). I even want to add some more settimeout functions here. The links i have seen solving problems like this are for linear progression, like clock countdown and such. But I have some irregular pattern of intervals. So is there some better, more sophisticated way to do  this... Here is my code:

```
  function betterBlitzColor() {

  $(".playerInfoCoatTwo").animate({ backgroundColor: "transparent" }, 20);
  setTimeout(function () {
    $(".playerInfoCoatTwo").animate({ backgroundColor: "black" }, 20)
    setTimeout(function () {
      $(".playerInfoCoatTwo").animate({ backgroundColor: "transparent" }, 20)
        setTimeout(function () {
          $(".playerInfoCoatTwo").animate({ backgroundColor: "black" }, 20)
          setTimeout(function () {
            $(".playerInfoCoatTwo").animate({ backgroundColor: "transparent" }, 20)
            setTimeout(function () {
              $(".playerInfoCoatTwo").animate({ backgroundColor: "black" }, 20)
              if(myRandomNumberBetween(1, 100) > 10)
              {
                setTimeout(function () {
                  $(".playerInfoCoatTwo").animate({ backgroundColor: "transparent" }, 20)
                  setTimeout(function () {
                    $(".playerInfoCoatTwo").animate({ backgroundColor: "black" }, 20)
                    if(myRandomNumberBetween(1, 100) > 10)
                    {
                      setTimeout(function () {
                        $(".playerInfoCoatTwo").animate({ backgroundColor: "transparent" }, 20)
                        setTimeout(function () {
                          $(".playerInfoCoatTwo").animate({ backgroundColor: "black" }, 20)
                            setTimeout(function () {
                              $(".playerInfoCoatTwo").animate({ backgroundColor: "transparent" }, 20)
                              setTimeout(function () {
                                $(".playerInfoCoatTwo").animate({ backgroundColor: "black" }, 20)
                                setTimeout(betterBlitzColor, myRandomNumberBetween(5000, 5000));   // inside 
                              }, 150)
                            }, 100)
                        }, 100)
                    }, 400) // level 3

                    }
                    else{
                      setTimeout(betterBlitzColor, myRandomNumberBetween(5000, 5000));   // inside 
                    }
                  }, 300)
              }, 650) // level 2

              }
              else{

                setTimeout(betterBlitzColor, myRandomNumberBetween(5000, 5000));   // inside 
              }
            }, 50)
          }, 50)
        }, 150)
    }, 50)
  }, 300)

  }
```

All I can say is that this code really looks weird. There must be some better way that this... 
The links I have visited solve problems more like this:

[Nested setTimeout alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574571/nested-settimeout-alternative)

I dont know how would I use that here in my case. Some help or suggestions?

Comment: What's the point of `setTimeout(betterBlitzColor, myRandomNumberBetween(5000, 5000))`? If the function name does what its sounds like it does, why not `setTimeout(betterBlitzColor, 5000)`?

Comment: those numbers are set  just so I could better see if all functions gppd or not. For normal use it would be something like this. setTimeout(betterBlitzColor, myRandomNumberBetween(9000, 18000)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `animate` calls are always to the same element, and the set `backgroundColor` is predictable (transparent to black to transparent, and so on), all of that functionality can be abstracted into a function. To chain it easily, you could have that function return a `Promise` that resolves after the desired amount of time, allowing you to use `.then`s or `await` without callback nesting. In addition, because you often do many animations (after delays) in a row, you could pass an array of the number of ms to wait between each animation, and use a loop to animate and then `await` a `Promise` that resolves after that many ms.

Something else that can reduce indentation hell is to *return early* when you have an alternation between a long code block and a short code block. That is, as with your `if (myRandomNumberBetween(1, 100) > 10) {` tests, instead of

```
if (test1) {
  // many lines 1
  if (test2) {
    // many lines 2

    // many more lines
  } else {
    // do something else 1
} else {
  // do something else 2
}
```

It's pretty unreadable - which test is each `do something else` connected to? It's not immediately obvious, which is a problem. Rather, you can do something like:

```
if (!test) {
  // do something else 1
  return;
}
// many lines 1
if (!test2) {
  // do something else 2
  return;
}
// many lines 2
```

Translating all of this to a fix of your original code:

```
// Animation part:
let isBlack = true;
function animate() {
  $(".playerInfoCoatTwo").animate({
    backgroundColor: isBlack ? "transparent" : 'black'
  }, 20);
  isBlack = !isBlack;
}

// Delay function,
// allows for much flatter code when you can `await` a `Promise` compared to `setTimeout`:
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
async function animateAndWait(msArr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < msArr.length; i++) {
    animate();
    await delay(msArr[i]);
  }
}

async function betterBlitzColor() {
  await animateAndWait([0, 300, 50, 150, 50, 50]);
  if (myRandomNumberBetween(1, 100) <= 10) {
    return delay(myRandomNumberBetween(9000, 18000))
      .then(betterBlitzColor);
  }
  await animateAndWait([650, 300]);
  if (myRandomNumberBetween(1, 100) <= 10) {
    return delay(myRandomNumberBetween(9000, 18000))
      .then(betterBlitzColor);
  }
  await animateAndWait([400, 100, 100, 150]);
  delay(myRandomNumberBetween(9000, 18000))
    .then(betterBlitzColor);
}
```

Comment: Wow dude thanks a lot. So this is this all the code that is equivalent to mine? Or i need to add something? Cause it looks super small compared to mine.

Comment: Yep, except for the `delay(myRandomNumberBetween(9000, 18000))` part (you can use `myRandomNumberBetween(5000, 5000)` instead if you want)

Comment: I don't want to be rude or anything but this code doesn't change the color back to black at the end of the function. It stays transparent. I can't figure it out because this is all new to me.  Maybe you forget the line of code before the first settimeout: $(".playerInfoCoatTwo").animate({ backgroundColor: "transparent" }, 20); Please help!

Comment: Those are all included in the initial `animateAndWait` call. If you want the first `300` to always correspond to an animation to `transparent`, you could set `isBlack` to `true` at the beginning of `animateAndWait` so that the odd number of items in the initial `msArr` won't cause problems.

Comment: Sorry man I get what you mean but it doesn't work. It stays transparent at the end of the every second turn.

Comment: Oh, I think I see the problem, your initial chunk has 5 `setTimeout`s but 6 `.animate` calls. Add a `0` to the beginning of the array in the initial `animateAndWait` call

Comment: Yes, that helped a lot. I can't say thanks enough man. Have a nice day!